# Не срабатывает условие User.IsInRole()

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity-2

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь реализовать такое: есть 2 роли - админ и юзер, если логинится админ ему дается доступ к админке, а если логинится юзер его перенаправляет на главную страницу сайта: 
Вот код метода `Login`:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);        

    if (user == null)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Failed login or pass");
    }
    else
    {
        ClaimsIdentity claim = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            IsPersistent = true
        } , claim);

        if(User.IsInRole("admin"))
        {
            RedirectToAction("Adminka", "Home");
        }else if(User.IsInRole("user"))
        {
            RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }        
    ViewBag.returnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View(model);
}

public ActionResult Logout()
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
    return RedirectToAction("Login");
}
```

Тут инициализирую роли для БД:

```
public class AppDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ApplicationContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(ApplicationContext context)
    {
        var userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));
        var roleAdmin = new IdentityRole { Name = "admin" };
        var roleUser = new IdentityRole { Name = "user" };

        roleManager.Create(roleAdmin);
        roleManager.Create(roleUser);

        var admin = new ApplicationUser { Email = "somemail@mail.ru", UserName = "somemail@mail.ru" };
        string password = "12345678";

        var result = userManager.Create(admin, password);

        if(result.Succeeded)
        {
            userManager.AddToRole(admin.Id, roleAdmin.Name);
            userManager.AddToRole(admin.Id, roleUser.Name);
        }

        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

В БД роли проверил существуют , и при регистрации юзерам сразу предоставляется роль user. Скажите пожалуйста почему не отрабатывает `if(User.IsInRole)`? У меня что юзера обычного, что админа - перенаправляет на `Home/Index`.  Может я не в том классе пишу проверку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я не ошибаюсь, то у вас после SignIn в контексте User отсутствуют роли, попробуй так :

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
          if (user != null)
          {
                await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
                {
                     //Если администратор
                     if (UserManager.IsInRole(user.Id, "admin"))
                     {
                         return RedirectToAction("Adminka", "Home");
                     }
                     //Если пользователь
                     if (UserManager.IsInRole(user.Id, "user"))
                     {
                         return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                     }
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                 }
          }
          else
          {
                 ModelState.AddModelError("", "Неверное имя пользователя или пароль.");
          }
   }
   return View(model);
}
```

Comment: да пробовал этот код уже, находил в интернете но почему то админа редиректит тоже на главную может что нужно в web.config сделать??

Comment: а сработало, ура спасибо